# Execute if database exists flutter

Tags: flutter

So basically what i want to do is:

When the user turns on the app for the first time,
The SQLite database is created and the data is fetched from the internet.
Until this is done, SetupPage() widget is displayed in scaffolds body or else Home() is displayed.

Now the code i wrote works perfectly for the first time, but when i open it the second time,
The SetupPage() only shows, it never goes back to the Home(). What am i doing wrong here ?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'pages/home.dart';
import 'pages/SetUpPage.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() {
    return AppState();
  }
}

class AppState extends State<App> {
  final bgColor = const Color(0xFF1abc9c);
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  bool status = false;

  Database database;

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeData();
    super.initState();
  }

  void initializeData() async
  {
    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, 'demo.db');
    status = false;
    Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {

      await db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE news (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, topic TEXT, img TEXT, newstitle TEXT, news TEXT, newslink TEXT)');

      fetchData();
    }
    );

    database.close();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("UnFound News"),
        backgroundColor: bgColor,
      ),

      body: status ? Home() : SetUpPage(),
    );
  }

  /*Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
            );*/

  void fetchData() async {
    var result = await get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/a0bvu");
    var arr = json.decode(result.body)['post'];

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      //TODO: Implement addition to database.
    }

    setState(() {
      status = true;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You're calling fetchData() in the onCreate parameter of the openDatabase function. Move it from there to before database.close()

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to put the `fetchData` in a `onOpen` parameter instead of the `onCreate` parameter like this:

```
Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
     onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {

         await db.execute(
              'CREATE TABLE news (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, topic TEXT, img TEXT, newstitle TEXT, news TEXT, newslink TEXT)');

         await fetchData();

    }, onOpen: (Database db) async {
        setState(() {
            status = true;
        });
    });
```

Comment: i dont want to fetch the data everytime i open the db, it should be only once when the db is created.

Comment: @FeminDharamshi Okay, then you should probably take the `status = true` out of the fetchData and put it into `onOpen`. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

```
      static Database _db;

      Future<Database> get db async {
        if(_db != null)
          return _db;
        _db = await initDb();
        return _db;
      }

      //Creating a database with name test.dn in your directory
      initDb() async {
        io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "test.db");
        var theDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
        return theDb;
      }
checkDb(){
//do operation
 var dbClient = await db;

}
```